# How to design my chat app

Tags: android

I have this chat application but because it only has one `textview` that being appended I don't know how to make it more presentable via designs I learnt the code from the internet and it is the easiest way I can do it can you help me guys?

Here is the code.

```
    private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;

private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){
        chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_conversation.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

        if(chat_user_name.contains(pref.getString("username","").toString())){
            chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name + " : " + chat_msg + " \n");

        }else {
            chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name + " : " + chat_msg + " \n");
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:src="@drawable/send"/>


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/msg_input"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_send" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/msg_input" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you sirs!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the TextView dynamically for each message.

To add the TextView dynamically, check this sample code

```
//Get the parent layout
RealtiveLayout relativeLayout  = (RealtiveLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

//New TextView
TextView textView = new TextView(this);

//Layout Params
textView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setText("Your text");

//Add to the parent
relativelayout.addView(textView1);
```

Comment: How can I add the new view below the existing one sir? Because it just overlaps

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and set the orientation to vertical.

Comment: When I changed it to LinearLayout sir the text didnt show anymore.

Comment: Have you set the orientation?   layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);